# React JS - Clear child forms on Tab clicks

Tags: reactjs, tabs, react-bootstrap

**Problem Statement** : 
I have a parent component which shows React-Bootstrap Tabs. There are 2 tabs inside the Tabs component each having its own state. I need to clear the state of child components when I am switching between tabs in the parent component.

E.g. My parent component shows "Search" and "Create" Tabs. When I go to "Create" tabs and perform create functionality, then create tab shows some success message. Now, when I move to Search tab and come back to Create Tab, all the messages and input fields still shows the previous values which I have entered. However, I need to clear the state of "Create" tab when I am coming back from "Search" tab.

Sample Code :

```
<Tab eventKey="search" title="Search">
            <Search />
          </Tab>
          <Tab eventKey="create" title="Create">
            <Create />
          </Tab>
```

Is there a react lifecycle method which I can use to clear the states of child components ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Tabs` accepts a boolean prop `unmountOnExit`. That should re-instantiate `<Create />` component when re-entered, effectively reset its internal state.

```
<Tabs unmountOnExit />
  <Tab eventKey="search" title="Search">
    <Search />
  </Tab>
  <Tab eventKey="create" title="Create">
    <Create />
</Tab>
```

Answer (score 2):

In react `componentDidMount()` or `componentWillMount()` will be called only once and it is same with the constructor too, `render()` will be called again and again whenever the state changes. This is the default life-cycle or react component.

However you can force the react component to restart its life-cycle by passing a different `key` prop, this will make react think it is a new component.

Do something like this :

```
<Create key = {"somekey" + Math.random() * 100} />
```

Just one more trick, there are many ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that clear. Based on what i understood, both  and  components are rendered at all times. So, when you switch between tabs, components don't get unmounted. And since there is no change in state of its parent component, re-render won't be caused. Lifecycle methods won't be able to help you.

One way to fix it would be like this. Inside the parent component of both Tabs, hold the eventKey in state. Pass function to both tabs to toggle it. And conditionally render one of the tabs. Render of parent would be something like this:

```
render() {
this.state.eventKey === "search" ? (<Tab eventKey="search" title="Search">
        <Search />
      </Tab>): <Tab eventKey="create" title="Create">
        <Create />
      </Tab>
}
```

Hope this helps!

@hackape's solution is the most accurate one based on the component library you are using. Try that. It should fix the issue

Comment: Thanks Aman for your answer. The solution given by @hackape's works. I am going with that implementation.